# Is there a multivariate joint Amoroso distribution?

Tags: distributions, joint-distribution, generalization

The [Amoroso distribution](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3274) is a remarkable feat of abstraction as it exactly or asymptotically generalizes dozens of named probability distributions. Is there a published/pre-published treatment of multivariate Amoroso distributions? Either the cumulative density function (CDF) or the probability density function (PDF) would be acceptable answers.

Comment: One might be able to find a joint distribution by using a copula, such as the maximum positive dependence copula. However, this seems unnatural to me. If it isn't too indulgent of me to require this, please avoid such a direct use of copulas.

Answer (score 3):

This is so far not a full answer.  The Amoroso distribution is a generalization of [the generalized gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution), obtained by parametrizing its range (by replacing $x$ with $x-a$ so the lower bound of the range is no longer 0). So how do we obtain the generalized gamma?

We can do that by Weibullizing a standard gamma distribution. Start with the Gamma distribution with density in the form
$$
f(x)\; dx = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^\alpha e^{\frac{x}{\theta}} \; \frac{dx}{x}
$$
Now introduce a new parameter $k$ by replacing $\frac{x}{\theta}$ with $\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^k$ (and recalculate the normalizing factor). The result of this Weibullization is the generalized gamma distribution.

Now, there are [multiple ways to define a multivariate gamma distribution](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=multivariate+gamma+distribution), start with one of them and try Weibullization.

Comment: I am not familiar with [Weibullization](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Weibullization), but it sounds promising.

Comment: [Pauw *et al* 2010](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268429861_Densities_of_composite_weibullized_generalized_gamma_variables) *prima facie* appears related.